# Microsoft Teams and Sharepoint server

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, microsoft-teams, integration

I have a SharePoint solution in SharePoint 2016 and I need to schedule a meeting from the Microsoft team and show it in my SharePoint calendar list Is it possible?

What's kind of integration and the available API to integrate Microsoft teams and SharePoint on-prem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Microsoft Graph to interact with Microsoft Teams from your SharePoint 2016 environment. You would need to create your own custom solution to call the API and update your SharePoint calendar accordingly. More information on using the Microsoft Graph with Microsoft Teams can be found here:

[Use the Microsoft Graph API to work with Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)